# Why does my program keep skipping out an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, arduino

My program is designed to change gears of a bike using DC motors with encoders. I have a few if statements so far basically saying if a button is pressed then run the motor until the position is met then turn off the motor. For example this first statement would be moving from gear 1 to gear 2. Then I have another statement saying if the button is pressed again then the motor will move to the next position. But when I run my program it skips the first statement because it doesn't stop at the position in the first if statement and keeps running until it gets to the position of the next if statement. I can't figure out why it does this. This is the code:

```
#define ENCA 2 // PINK
#define ENCB 3 // YELLOW

// this constant won't change:
//const int buttonPin2 = 3;
const int  buttonPin = 4;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
//const int ledPin = 13;       // the pin that the LED is attached to

//Motor A

int PWM = 5;
int in2 = 6;
int in1 = 7;

// Variables will change:
int pos = 0;
int buttonPushCounter = 1;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
//int buttonState2 = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button
//int lastButtonState2 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ENCA, INPUT);
  pinMode(ENCB, INPUT);
  pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ENCA), readEncoder, RISING);
  Serial.println("target pos");
  // initialize the button pin as a input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  //  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);


  // initialize motor pins
  pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

  if (buttonPushCounter == 1) {
  GearOneTwo();
  }
  if (buttonPushCounter == 2) {
  GearTwoThree();
  }
  PrintData();

}
void GearOneTwo() {

  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    //if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      buttonPushCounter++;
      Serial.print("Current Gear: ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
      //Turn on motor A
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      analogWrite(PWM, 255);
     }
  }
  if (pos >= 807) {
  MotorOff();
  }
  //    delay(50);
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}

void GearTwoThree() {

  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    //if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      buttonPushCounter++;
      Serial.print("Current Gear: ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
      //Turn on motor A
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      analogWrite(PWM, 255);
    }
  }
  if (pos >= 2000) {
  MotorOff();
  }
  //    delay(50);
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}

void PrintData() {
    int target = 888;
    Serial.print(target);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(pos);
    Serial.println();
}

void MotorOff() {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
}

void readEncoder() {
    int b = digitalRead(ENCB);
    if (b > 0) {
        pos++;
        }
    else {
        pos--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - [edit] your post and indent the code correctly

Comment: I hope it is better now.

Comment: Has your development environment a debugger with a step by step execution?

Comment: @MatG I'm using an Arduino so it doesn't have a debugger. I was wondering if I was making a simple mistake that someone could look through my code line by line and see why the if statement :   'if (pos >= 807) {
  MotorOff();
  }'    is being skipped

Comment: @D.Fechner Ok, so maybe `pos` has values that you don't expect. Have you tested if the encoder is working? What's the `int` returned by `digitalRead`?

Comment: @MatG The encoder works fine. The position keeps counting up until it gets to 2000 then its turns the motor off. But it should first stop running 807 then wait for another button press to run to 2000. Here are some values of the pos: 888 2051
888 2053
888 2054
888 2055
888 2055
888 2056
888 2056
888 2056
888 2056
888 2056
888 2056
888 2056
888 is just a target that I have set and doesn't effect the program. It stops at 2056 because when it reaches 2000 and stops the motor, the motor doesn't instantly stop.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are counting the encoder: on the rise of A channel you read the status of B? Where you saw that technique? If there is noise on the A signal doesn't seem good to me.

Comment: @MatG someone has answered so don't worry anymore but thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: if motor reach to the desired position then `buttonPushCounter++`

```cpp
#define ENCA 2 // PINK
#define ENCB 3 // YELLOW

// this constant won't change:
//const int buttonPin2 = 3;
const int  buttonPin = 4;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
//const int ledPin = 13;       // the pin that the LED is attached to

//Motor A

int PWM = 5;
int in2 = 6;
int in1 = 7;

// Variables will change:
int pos = 0;
int buttonPushCounter = 1;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
//int buttonState2 = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button
//int lastButtonState2 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ENCA, INPUT);
  pinMode(ENCB, INPUT);
  pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ENCA), readEncoder, RISING);
  Serial.println("target pos");
  // initialize the button pin as a input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  //  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);


  // initialize motor pins
  pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

  if (buttonPushCounter == 1) {
  GearOneTwo();
  }
  if (buttonPushCounter == 2) {
  GearTwoThree();
  }
  PrintData();

}
void GearOneTwo() {

  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    //if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      Serial.print("Current Gear: ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
      //Turn on motor A
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      analogWrite(PWM, 255);
     }
  }
  if (pos >= 807) {
  MotorOff();
  buttonPushCounter++;
  }
  //    delay(50);
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}

void GearTwoThree() {

  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    //if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      Serial.print("Current Gear: ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
      //Turn on motor A
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      analogWrite(PWM, 255);
    }
  }
  if (pos >= 2000) {
  MotorOff();
  buttonPushCounter++;
  }
  //    delay(50);
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}

void PrintData() {
    int target = 888;
    Serial.print(target);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(pos);
    Serial.println();
}

void MotorOff() {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
}

void readEncoder() {
    int b = digitalRead(ENCB);
    if (b > 0) {
        pos++;
        }
    else {
        pos--;
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, check your `pos`.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I can't quite see what you did though, please could you let me know

Comment: program must wait untill motor reachs to the first position and then **buttonPushCounter** changes